# Get versioned string name of font

Tags: css, webpack, laravel-mix, tailwind-css, postcss

)

I'd like to prefetch the fonts I generated using Tailwindcss.

I included the font this way:

```
@layer base {

       /* lato-300 - latin */
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Lato';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 300;
        src: local('Lato Light'), local('Lato-Light'),
        url('../fonts/lato-v16-latin-300.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */ url('../fonts/lato-v16-latin-300.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */ url('../fonts/lato-v16-latin-300.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */ url('../fonts/lato-v16-latin-300.svg#Lato') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
        font-display: swap;
    }
    /* lato-300italic - latin */
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Lato';
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: 300;
        src: local('Lato Light Italic'), local('Lato-LightItalic'),
        url('../fonts/lato-v16-latin-300italic.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */ url('../fonts/lato-v16-latin-300italic.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */ url('../fonts/lato-v16-latin-300italic.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */ url('../fonts/lato-v16-latin-300italic.svg#Lato') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
        font-display: swap;
    }
}
```

Now I process my css using Laravel-mix:

```
const {EnvironmentPlugin} = require ('webpack');
const mix = require ('laravel-mix');
const glob = require ('glob');
const path = require ('path');
const {CleanWebpackPlugin} = require ('clean-webpack-plugin');
const ChunkRenamePlugin = require ('webpack-chunk-rename-plugin');
const TargetsPlugin = require('targets-webpack-plugin');

require ('laravel-mix-tailwind');
require('laravel-mix-polyfill');
require('laravel-mix-brotli');

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.webpackConfig ({
    output: {
        chunkFilename: 'js/chunks/[name].[chunkhash].js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin ({
            cleanOnceBeforeBuildPatterns: ['js/chunks/**/*']
        }),
        new EnvironmentPlugin ({
            BASE_URL: '/'
        }),
        new ChunkRenamePlugin ({
            initialChunksWithEntry: true,
            '/js/app': 'js/app.js',
            '/js/vendor': 'js/vendor.js',
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /node_modules(?:\/|\\).+\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: [['@babel/preset-env', {targets: 'last 2 versions, ie >= 10'}]],
                    plugins: ['@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring', '@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread', '@babel/plugin-transform-template-literals'],
                    babelrc: false
                }
            },
            {
                enforce: 'pre',
                test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
                loader: 'eslint-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.join (__dirname, 'resources'),
            'node_modules': path.join (__dirname, 'node_modules')
        }
    },
});

mix.js ('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
.postCss ('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css')
.tailwind ('./tailwind.config.js');

if (mix.inProduction ()) {
    mix
    .version ()
    .polyfill({
        enabled: true,
        useBuiltIns: "usage",
        targets: "> 0.25%, not dead",
        corejs: 3
    })
    .brotli();
}
```

This is what my processed css looks like:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';

  font-style: italic;

  font-weight: 300;

  src: local('Lato Light Italic'), local('Lato-LightItalic'),
        url(/fonts/lato-v16-latin-300italic.woff2?a21767e20d27a9c06007c981a8e5f827) format('woff2'),  url(/fonts/lato-v16-latin-300italic.woff?8e90b967ea69fc68b130d36cc34d41c0) format('woff'),  url(/fonts/lato-v16-latin-300italic.ttf?329d60785944501134891f948f41c001) format('truetype'),  url(/fonts/lato-v16-latin-300italic.svg?17e346950dce164549968b7b93d48f2d#Lato) format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */

  font-display: swap;
}
```

Somehow I need to find a way to include those versioned font-calls to my prefetching.

My first attempt was to iterate over all files in `public/fonts`, but of course I don't get the versioned url:

```
@foreach(File::files(public_path('fonts')) as $font)
    <link rel="preload" href="/fonts/{{$font->getFilename()}}" as="font">
@endforeach
```

An idea that I had was to add the urls to `mix-manifest.json`, but I'm kinda stuck here :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given enough context there may better ways to address the underlying problem you're trying to solve, but building on top of what you already have, I would next create a helper function:

```php
function fontVersion($filename){
  $source = file_get_content(public_path('css/app.css'));
  $start = strpos($source, $filename) + strlen($filename);
  $end = strpos($source, ')', $start);
  return substr($source, $start, $end - $start);
}
```

And then call it in my view to add the version string to my URL:

```
@foreach(File::files(public_path('fonts')) as $font)
    <link rel="preload" href="/fonts/{{ $font->getFilename() . fontVersion(filename) }}" as="font">
@endforeach
```

Here's a [live demo](https://ideone.com/fe1LFK) with slight modifications for your reference.

Comment: After applying a little fix (`file_get_contents`) this works out :-) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you want, so here are two options:

---

This will stop the processing of URLs, preserving the font

```
.options({
        processCssUrls: false,
})
```

---

You might be able to use this in the CSS to preserve the font

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rowdies:wght@300&display=swap');
```

the only issue is if the font is custom from the css you might need to create the website for the font to be called from

Answer (score 1):

So here's a cleaner way to do this. You can fetch the list of assets in webpack.mix.js and generate your preload code:

```
mix.then((stats) => {
    let preload = [];
    for (let file of Object.keys(stats.compilation.assets)) {
        if (file.indexOf("woff2") == -1) {
            continue;
        }
        preload.push(`<link rel="preload" href="${file}" as="font" type="font/woff2" crossorigin></link>`);
    }
    fs.writeFileSync("public/preload.txt", preload.join("\n"));
});
```

Include that in your blade.

```
<?php @include public_path('preload.txt'); ?>
```